# Didactic model for tipping dynamics

Tags: education, earth, complex-systems, models, critical-phenomena

I would like to know if there are some toy models that describe a system dynamic from ecology or earth science with some feedback loops (eg. ice-sheet cover, rainforest-savanna cover, permafrost thawing ) in which a critical threshold can be observed, i.e. such that depending on some parameter, or on the initial condition, the asymptotic behaviour split in one or more different state. These should be easy enough to be tought to students with basic tools of dynamical systems, but complex enough to describe the different dynamics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Comment: to me it's about geophysics dynamics and their modeling, in particular it's about how to teach and divulgate about their peculiar behaviours through easy examples. Could you elaborate on why it is not about physics in you opinion?

Comment: Are the students kids or uni students?

Comment: It's easily re-phrased: "Which possibly simple and easy to grasp systems exhibit tipping dynamics?" There, now it's a question about physics...

Comment: The question is closed. Still, check the book "Phase Transitions" by Ricard V. Solé (2011).

Comment: The students are in a university course in natural sciences, they have access to basic dynamical system and analysis knowledge